# ASP.NET create link to toggled content

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, toggle

I'm using bootstrap and asp.net.  I have a toggle-data to toggle what is shown on the page.  I would like to create  links on other pages which would go to this page and automatically show a specified view.  Currently, my link just brings me to the page but D1 is still being shown, instead of D2.

View:

```
<h2>
    SOO Sample</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active"><a href="#D1" data-toggle="tab">Active</a></li>
            <li><a href="#D2" data-toggle="tab">What I want to be active If i click on a d2 link to this page.</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="D1">

                <p>showing</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="D2">

                <p> show me if I came to this pagae from a different link.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I found that I thought should work.

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("No Click me instead", "action", "Controller", null, null, "D2", null, null)%>
```

The url that it links to is the same as the link that I see when I hover over D2 so the creation of the url is working correctly, it's just not playijng nice with the css, any ideas?

The link that it creates: `http://localhost:numbers/dir/action#D2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script did the job.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = document.location.toString();
                if (url.match('#')) {
                    $('.nav-pills a[href=#' + url.split('#')[1] + ']').tab('show');
                }
            });
    </script>
```